# How to use fuzzywuzzy efficiently in python?

Tags: python, pandas, text, similarity, fuzzywuzzy

I want to compute the similarity of column Aname from dataframe Apple to column Bname from dataframe Banana, and create a new column in dataframe A that shows the similarity, my code is as follows:

```
Bname = []
similarity = []
for i in Apple.Aname:
        ratio = process.extract( i, Banana.Bname, limit=1)
        Bname.append(ratio[0][0])
        similarity.append(ratio[0][1])
Apple['Bname'] = pd.Series(Bname)
Apple['similarity'] = pd.Series(similarity)
```

However, there are over 400,000 rows in dataframe Apple and over 700,000 rows in dataframe Banana, my code runs for hours and I still haven't get the result. I wonder how to do it more efficiently? Or at least how could I know the progress of my code? Thanks a lot for your great help in advance!

Comment: This will have complexity O(N*M). In other words, you are attempting to compute 280,000,000,000 pairwise distance calculations. That will take far too long.  You need to find a different approach to solve your problem, or find a way to reduce the size of your data.

Comment: For instance, are there many duplicate strings in either list? Can they be eliminated first?  Or do you expect to see many exact matches which can be detected via a simple pandas merge? That will be a faster way to detect the easy cases. Then you can use fuzzy matching for the remainder.

Comment: [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) is one way to make this problem tractable. Essentially, you compress each name to a short soundex code, and then only run your expensive fuzzywuzzy match on entries with matching Soundex codes. Since you're only using an exact match Soundex match, you can use faster techniques for searching, like indexes.